# How to get the Eagle ULP file name?

Tags: eaglecad

In Eagle CAD software (ver. 5.12), how do I get the file name of the User Language Program (ULP) from inside this program (programmatically)?

I only know how to get the name of the schematic, board or library. For example, to get the board name:

```
board(B) printf(B.name);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out.

> Command line arguments are available to the program through the global
>   Builtin Variables argc and argv.

So the following renders the file name of the user language program (same as in a C program):

```
printf(argv[0]);
```